# url rewrite to short url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good days guys, I need your help with this url rewrite.

The are two rewrites I want to do.

1) I want to take out `.php` from the url even though my files is saved as `.php`

2) I want to rewrite the url below

If you can help me. It will be lovely. Thanks

Comment: But your desired URL has no logic ...

Comment: Explain yourself to me please @Mihai

Comment: `Sef` is a parameter and so is `pid` and you want `?Sef=shoes/pid/3` .... `shoes/pid/3` becomes a variable to `Sef` parameter ... it has no logic ... how would you know which is which ?

Comment: @mihai I see your point. But is they no way I can use php to change it?

Comment: @Jessica check anub's answer should work just fine for removing the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```